# Why did the 'human biology' chat room get deleted

Tags: discussion, chat

I created the 'human biology chat room' since a quite long conversation I had in the comment section of a human-related answer.

Why did the room get deleted? (I suppose it was, since I came back one day and it was not there anymore...)

Is there some sort of 'delete unused room' policy on SE? Or is it that some high-rep user wasn't happy with it?

If it is the latter, I would like to know the reason... please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat rooms are automatically deleted for inactivity. There were no posts in that room for 7 days so it was automatically removed by the system.

[Here is more information about the chat room retention policy](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention).